# how to add new options to form in validator API?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I would like to know if it's possible to add an option to the validator after initializing the form.

For ex:

I initialize the form like this.

```
$("#form").validate({errorElement: "em"});
```

and later if I want to add `errorContainer`, how would I do it?

Answer (score 1):

> later if I want to add `errorContainer`, how would I do it?

Once the plugin is initialized, you cannot "dynamically" add or change any options for this plugin.  The author has not provided a method for this.

You can only dynamically alter the rules using the `.rules()` method.